# How can I search AD for a name in the Description Field with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

We format our AD descriptions as follows.
3 character Site Code - Real Name - Model - Serial - Financial status - Warranty Exp Date.
Example:
ABC - John Doe - 840 G6 - abc123xyz - (L) - 01/01/2024

I need to be able to search AD and filter for the Real Name "John Doe" in the description
Here is what I have tried.

```
(Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=xxxx,OU=yyyy,OU=zzzz,DC=123,DC=456" -Filter {Description -Like "Doe"} -Properties Description).Description | Out-GridView
```

This does not give an error but doesn't give any results.

The suggestion below worked perfectly for the CLI but I am trying to add this to a GUI Here is the entire script. Keep in mind this will eventually pass the result "Computer Name" to a text box and will have a button to disable the computer.

```
Add-Type -Name Window -Namespace Console -MemberDefinition '
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow);'

[void][Console.Window]::ShowWindow([Console.Window]::GetConsoleWindow(), 0)
<# 
.NAME
    Template
#>

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()



$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(400,400)
$Form.text                       = "Form"
$Form.TopMost                    = $false

$Lbl_Leaver                      = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Lbl_Leaver.Text                 = "Leaver Name"
$Lbl_Leaver.AutoSize             = $true
$Lbl_Leaver.width                = 25
$Lbl_Leaver.height               = 10
$Lbl_Leaver.location             = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(11,8)
$Lbl_Leaver.Font                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$Tbx_Leaver                      = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Tbx_Leaver.Text                 = ""
$Tbx_Leaver.multiline            = $false
$Tbx_Leaver.width                = 200
$Tbx_Leaver.height               = 20
$Tbx_Leaver.location             = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,43)
$Tbx_Leaver.Font                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$Btn_Submit                      = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Btn_Submit.Text                 = "Submit"
$Btn_Submit.width                = 60
$Btn_Submit.height               = 30
$Btn_Submit.location             = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(28,88)
$Btn_Submit.Font                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)
$Btn_Submit.Add_Click({ Find_Leaver_Devices })

$Tbx_Results                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Tbx_Results.Text                = ""
$Tbx_Results.multiline           = $false
$Tbx_Results.width               = 100
$Tbx_Results.height              = 20
$Tbx_Results.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(13,192)
$Tbx_Results.Font                = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)


$Form.controls.AddRange(@($Lbl_Leaver,$Tbx_Leaver,$Btn_Submit,$Tbx_Results))



Function Find_Leaver_Devices {
$Leaver = "*$Tbx_Leaver.Text*"
(Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=123,OU=456,OU=abc,DC=def,DC=ghi" -Filter {Description -Like $Leaver} -Properties *) | Select-Object Name, Description | Out-GridView -Passthru
}


[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, `-LDAPFilter "(Description=*John Doe*)"` should be it. You're missing wildcards in your statement as well as using a scriptblock `{ }` is not well supported by the AD Cmdlets. Always use a string expression

Answer (score 0):

`-Filter`s should be strings rather than scriptblocks, and `-like` is designed to be used with simple wildcards. Try

```
(Get-ADComputer -SearchBase ... -Filter "Description -like '*Doe*'" -Properties Description).Description ...
```